# Create a dynamic temporary table from another table have a single column using procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to create a temporary table from another table dynamically creating stored procedure.

I have a table named as Tblstructure. This table has only 1 column Colname. Data in the column is created at run time and is going to change every time. For time being I have data

```
Colname
-------
Region
Country
State
Metric
Value
```

I want to use the above table and create a dynamic table having column as

```
Region  Country  state  Metric  value.
```

Whenever users call the stored procedure, Procedure call the table tblstructure pull out all the rows from the table and transform them into column header.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to look into are patterns for concatenating text stored across the rows in a table. This resource lays out some common patterns you should read about: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

That said, the XML path pattern is the one I most frequently employ.

```
CREATE TABLE Tblstructure (Colname varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Tblstructure (Colname)
VALUES ('Region'), ('Country'), ('State'), ('Metric'), ('Value');

DECLARE @ColumnDeclaration VARCHAR(2000) =
    STUFF(
        (SELECT ', ' + Colname + ' VARCHAR(50) '
         FROM Tblstructure
         FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    , 1, 1, '')

SELECT 'CREATE TABLE SomeTempTable (' + @ColumnDeclaration + ');'
```

Output: `CREATE TABLE SomeTempTable ( Region VARCHAR(50) , Country VARCHAR(50) , State VARCHAR(50) , Metric VARCHAR(50) , Value VARCHAR(50) );`

Notice that I had to make an assumption about the type that should represent each field. I have assumed each field is a `VARCHAR(50)`, but you would probably want to figure out a better way of inferring what type each field should be.

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4434/23

**Edit**

Also, keep in mind that this example wouldn't actually create the table, it just gives you the dynamic create table statement. To execute this, you would want to feed the resulting create table statement into sp_executesql.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me try this